# How to use WPF Custom Controls/Styles library in VSIX project?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, vsix

i have a vsix with a custom wizard, i want to use WPF as a wizard and i can create a window and show my wizard, now i want to use Fluent WPF styles which included in a Library/nuget:

https://github.com/InkoreStudios/UI.WPF.Modern

but i have issues with using this library. in a simple wpf desktop app, i can put this codes:

```
<ui:ThemeResources/>
<ui:XamlControlsResources/>
```

and i can use fluent styles/controls

now since there is no app.xaml file in vsix, i put this codes in my **Window.Resources**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ui:ThemeResources/>
            <ui:XamlControlsResources/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

and i get this exception:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'iNKORE.UI.WPF.Modern, PublicKeyToken=cd19e634b9706635' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'iNKORE.UI.WPF.Modern, PublicKeyToken=cd19e634b9706635' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

how i can use this library for my vsix? message say that file not found but i can see *.dlls in release/debug folder, and library is strong named assemblies signed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in top of your package class:

```
[ProvideBindingPath]
public sealed class YOURPROJECTPackage : AsyncPackage
```

Or we can use a AssemblyResolver:

```
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnAssemblyResolve;
    
    private Assembly OnAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

    if (args.Name.ToLower().Contains("iNKORE.UI.WPF.Modern") && !args.Name.ToLower().Contains("iNKORE.UI.WPF.Modern.Controls"))
    {
        path = Path.Combine(path, "iNKORE.UI.WPF.Modern.dll");
        Assembly ret = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
        return ret;
    }
 if (args.Name.ToLower().Contains("iNKORE.UI.WPF.Modern.Controls"))
    {
        path = Path.Combine(path, "iNKORE.UI.WPF.Modern.Controls.dll");
        Assembly ret = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
        return ret;
    }
    return null;
}
```